# How can I replace the resizable handle icon? react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

[image]I'm working on a dashboard where I want to replace the resizable icon at the bottom right corner of the grid item in react-grid-layout.

Is there a way to replace this icon with my own custom icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can add [resizable handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adHxh.png) into your grid-layout component

Comment: Please post your code as a code snippet using the ```. Links can die but pasted code on stack overflow lives forever!